# Highcharts, Set XAXIS only show certain time/number

Tags: javascript, php, json, codeigniter, highcharts

I want to create chart like this with highcharts, it is possible to set xAxis like image below?
I try to use tickpoints and tickinterval but still didn't get the result I wanted

[image: Text]

Sample of actual data,

[image: Text]

This is result I get now, i want to change xaxis into interval 30 minutes like first image
[image: Text]

My code

```
$.ajax({
        url: "",
        type: 'GET',
        dataType:'json',
            success: function(data) {
                // console.log(data) ;
                var chartSeriesData=[];
                var chartCatData=[];
                $.each(data, function(i,item){
                    var series_name = item.time;
                    var series_data = item.power; 
                    chartSeriesData.push(series_data);
                    chartCatData.push(series_name);
                });

Highcharts.chart('power', {

                    title: {text: ''},
                    subtitle: {text: ''},

                    yAxis: {
                        title: {text: ''}
                        // ,min: 0, max: 0.010
                    },
                    xAxis: {
                        categories: chartCatData,
                        title: {
                            text: ''
                        },
                        labels: {
                            enabled: true
                          }
                    },
                    legend: {
                        layout: 'vertical',
                        align: 'right',
                        verticalAlign: 'middle'
                    },
                    plotOptions: {
                        series: {
                          label: {
                            connectorAllowed: false
                          }
                        }
                    },

                    series: [
                    {
                        // name: 'Power',
                        data: chartSeriesData
                    }
                    ],
```

Result console.log(data)

[image: Text]

Comment: Hi @ian, That's because you're using `category` x-axis type. You should use `datetime` type and format your x values as timestamps in milliseconds. Could you add to the question a part of the result of `console.log(data);`?

Comment: Hi @ppotaczek, I updated my question with result of console.log(data);

Answer (score 0):

You should use `datetime` axis type and format your x values as timestamps in milliseconds.

```
const chartSeriesData = data.map(
    item => [new Date(item.date).getTime(), item.power]
);

Highcharts.chart('container', {
    xAxis: {
        type: 'datetime',
        tickInterval: 1000 * 60 * 30
    },
    series: [{
        data: chartSeriesData
    }]
});
```

---

**Live demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/vzepscjr/

**API Reference:** https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/xAxis

Comment: This is the result, xaxis not align
https://jsfiddle.net/dpLxym4n/2/

Comment: Hi @ian, What do you exactly mean? Probably enabling `startOnTick` and `endOnTick` properties will adapt the chart to your expectations. Example: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/er74d9nL/